# How can I write ZOQL (Zuora SQL) function which returns yesterday date?

Tags: dateadd, zuora

How can I write ZOQL (Zuora SQL) function which returns yesterday date?

I can not write this function. Zuora contains date_add function but I don't know the right syntax.

I tried to write this function with current term expression.

Maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below syntax in ZOQL. This is part of special date/time feature provided as part of zoql.

```
Select * from object where UpdatedDate = 'today - 1 day'
```

if you need to include date timestamp and go back exact one day, use 'now' instead of 'today' as shown below.

```
Select * from object where UpdatedDate = 'now - 1 day'
```

let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('DAY', -1, current_date)
```